# I need to find the largest ID (prim key) in table, get the value & use it insert a new row in my table-need to use datasource1.SelectCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

C# MSSql: I need to find the largest ID (primary key) in my table, get the value and use it to insert a new row in my table.  I need to use datasource1.SelectCommand.  I have tried sqlCommand, but that didn't work.
Below is the code as I have it so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class ListProperty : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

       //Other code here (Page_LOad, Dropdown list, etc)

        protected void OnButtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlProc1 = "SELECT row from PROPERTY ORDER BY Id DESC Limit 1";
            //SqlDataAdapter MxID = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlProc1,SqlDataSource1.SqlCacheDependency);
            //SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlProc1;
            //SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection();
            EntityDataSource cmd = new EntityDataSource();
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            Object returnValue;

            cmd.CommandText = sqlProc1;
            //cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            //cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            //sqlConnection1.Open();

            returnValue = cmd.CommandText;

            //sqlConnection1.Close();

            Object MxID = returnValue;
            MxID.ToString();
            int MxIDint = (Int32)MxID + 1;
            String strMxID = MxIDint.ToString();

            sqlProc1 = "INSERT INTO PROPERTY(ID,Property_ID,Type_ID,Coordinates) VALUES(" + strMxID + ",'1','1','0.')";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sqlProc1;
            //GridView1.DataBind();  //generates error
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you define "didn't work"? Did you not get the right value back from your first command? Did it not insert? Is it crashing? If so, what's the exception.

Comment: Try with `SELECT Top 1 row from PROPERTY ORDER BY Id DESC` for `sql-server`, `Limit` is for `MySQL`

Comment: if your ID is an auto-incrementing index, then you don't need to do this.  Simply insert your row and values without the ID, and the database will auto-magically calculate the ID for you.

Comment: I suggest using stored procedures and parameters. Inline SQL in code is just bad idea. Also look into the MAX() aggregate function in SQL.

Comment: Joe, that is what I originally tried to do, but though I have tried, I must not have the primary key set to auto-incrementing.  I tried to set this in the properties for the Id.  I must have done something wrong. If you don't mind would you please explain how to set Id to auto-incremting,

Comment: Sab669: I keep getting an error at the line:  int MxIDint = (Int32)MxID + 1;

Comment: @KES - Did you ever solve this problem?  If so, close it out and select an answer below.  Unfortunately, I somehow missed your question about the auto-incrementing ID in your earlier comment.  That, unfortunately, is an entirely new question on Stack Overflow.  Good Luck.

Comment: wow... I just looked at your code again, how did we miss this !?!   CommandText does not return the results of your query.  I'm not familiar with the EntityDataSource class, but I know that's not correct.

Answer (score 3):

use this SQL query:

```
select MAX(id) from PROPERTY;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
queryResult = dbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<int>("SELECT Max(Id) from PROPERTY ")
    .Single();
```

Check this out for more details:[get a scalar value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005901/entity-framework-code-first-execute-scalar-valued-functions?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Joe's suggestion to make the Id key self increment.  I had to figure out how do that on my own though.  I tried it before but I tried again and it did.