# How to get scalar value from a SQL statement in a .Net core application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The following code in a .Net core console application (EF core 2.0/Sql server).

```
var sql = _context.Set<string>()
          .FromSql("select dbo.FunctionReturnVarchar({0});", id);
```

got the following exception?

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'string' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

Is it a way without defining a class with a property of string?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862 At present you cannot use FromSql which returns a different shape than one of the entity types in the model

Comment: I have written an updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73333442/3604216)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`.Set<TEntity>()` is for entities backed by the context.

You can try a workaround

```
DbConnection connection = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();

using(DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {

    cmd.CommandText = "select dbo.FunctionReturnVarchar(@id)";    

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = id });

    if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) { 
        connection.Open();
    }

    var value = (string) await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
}

if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open)) { 
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I _think_ your `connection.Open[Async](); cmd.Execute[Async](); connection.Close[Async]()` should be wrapped in `using (Database.GetService<IConcurrencyDetector>().EnterCriticalSection()) { ... }` becouse `_context.Database.GetDbConnection()` dont give you your own instance of DbConnection (you are not disposing it, arent you). But i am not sure.

Answer (score 27):

What you need in this scenario is the [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions) method with bound output parameter:

```
var resultParameter = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.VarChar);
resultParameter.Size = 2000; // some meaningfull value
resultParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("set @result = FunctionReturnVarchar({0});", id, resultParameter);
var result = resultParameter.Value as string;
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE - they introduced the SqlQuery function in EF Core 7 to make this much more clean and convenient - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types

However, the documentation doesn't specifically cover what I would consider the most common use case - getting a single value:

```
var someIntValue = context.Database
.SqlQuery<int>($"SELECT Top 1 [SomeColumn] as [Value] FROM [SomeTable]")
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that you have to specify the column name "Value" when using SqlQuery in conjunction with LINQ operators (like FirstOrDefault).  Otherwise you will get the following error:

```
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 public static class TeeLinqExtensions
    {
        public static long? TeeNextSeq(this DatabaseContext pCtx)
        {
            long? seqNo=0;

            using (var command = pCtx.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR student_admin_no_seq AS seq";

                pCtx.Database.OpenConnection();

                  seqNo = command.ExecuteScalar() as long?;

                  pCtx.Database.CloseConnection();

            }

            return seqNo;

        }
    }
```

> then use as

```
 var studentIdentityNo = _db.TeeNextSeq();
```