# How do I retrieve the creation date of a SQL Server database with EF Core?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way for me to get the `create_date` property of `sys.databases` view in SQL Server with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Use `FromSqlRaw` maybe?

Comment: `.FromSqlRaw()` requires a `DbSet()`, which also would require a POCO class. Then also I don't know where the information from the view is stored, to see how the class should look like.

Comment: Maybe try `ExecuteSqlCommand` with an output parameter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163876/14868997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no direct way from EF Core. I ended up using a DB Command for this purpose:

```
DateTime res = new DateTime();
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT create_date FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = db_name()";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    context.Database.OpenConnection();

    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (result.Read())
        {
            res = (DateTime)result.GetValue("create_date");
        }
    }
}
return res;
```