# Cast Error in SQL Server when outputting an integer from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this for a stored procedure which outputs just an integer

```
ALTER PROC GetPendingReservations
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT FacilityAndAmenityId ) 
    FROM
        [Property].[PropAndAmenReservation] with(nolock)
    WHERE
        IsGranted = 'False' 
        AND CAST(StartDate AS DATE) = CAST(GetDate() AS DATE) 
        AND FacilityAndAmenityId NOT IN (SELECT FacilityAndAmenityId 
                                         FROM [Property].[PropAndAmenReservation] with(nolock)
                                         WHERE IsGranted = 'True' 
                                           AND CAST(StartDate AS DATE) = CAST(GetDate() AS DATE))
END
```

and I call it in my web api through this.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/getfacilitiesreservation")]
public int GetFacilitiesReservation()
{
            using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    const string query = "GetPendingReservations";

                    var count = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query);
                    return count;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
}
```

But I get this error in my catch exception:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

If I use `db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query)`, this is what I get:

[image]

Can you please show me how to this right? Thank you.

Comment: those ' with(nolock)" are a bad idea...

Comment: db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).ToString(); so it's a string.

Comment: Why Sir? I can remove that but I don't think it will resolve my issue.

Comment: Even if I change it to <String> I still get the same error.

Comment: What if you simply do `return db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query);` ?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT()` query returns int, you should use `db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query)`.

Comment: Please see my edit. using int was the first thing I did.

Comment: I just did it this way..... 'const string query = "GetPendingReservations";

                    var count = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).ToList();
                    return Convert.ToInt32(count[0]);'

Comment: Ok... the issue is `db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query)` returns the collection of `int`. You need to do `var items = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).ToList();` and then `return items[0];`

Comment: @Ibanez1408 use this `db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).First();` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to consider in your issue:

1) `SELECT COUNT()` query returns a scalar integer mentioning total row count.

2) `Database.SqlQuery<T>` used to execute raw SQL query returns instance of [`DbRawSqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbrawsqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) which implements `IEnumerable` collection and expects iteration to get values inside it.

Based from these considerations and method return type as `int`, you should return single value of query result like this:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    try
    {
        const string query = "GetPendingReservations";

        // First(), FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault() may also be used
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).Single();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // exception handling
    }
}
```

Similar issue: [Entity Framework Code-First Execute Scalar-Valued Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005901/entity-framework-code-first-execute-scalar-valued-functions)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a lot better than what I came up with!