# scalar function in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core, scalar

I have a scalar function in a database that returns string value and I want to fetch this value at the server-side through LINQ.
PS. The application I am developing is in .Net Core.

I tried different ways that are available over the internet to achieve this but found no luck.

Below are the links which I tried implementing

1. http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-scalar-function-mapping/
2. https://forums.asp.net/t/2055038.aspx?scalar+function+entity+framework
3. [Entity Framework Code-First Execute Scalar-Valued Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005901/entity-framework-code-first-execute-scalar-valued-functions)

First try:

```
var query = _context.StringValue.Select(d => Context.GetDetail(form.ValueString, "State"));
string x = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Second try:

```
IQueryable<UDFResult> state = _context.Query<UDFResult>().FromSql($"select dbo.GetDetail('{form.ValueString}','State') AS value");
List<UDFResult> l = state.ToList();
```

Any help will be appreciated and also I would be interested in seeing an example of how to achieve this.

[blank Result in second try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTDAT.png)

Comment: What issue you are facing here?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya,  I am not able to retrieve value from the query and getting exceptions.

When I fire below query in SQL

"select dbo.GetDetail('{form.ValueString}','State') AS value"

I get the required response. Now I am trying to get the same response via LINQ.

Comment: Can you share what exceptions you are getting and what are the messages of the exceptions?

Comment: You tried some things (good!), but what were the results? No answer, wrong answer, exception, compile error? Please provide details (as an edit)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, 
  


First try:


Exception: Invalid object name 'StringValue'.
But I have already declared "StringValue" in DbContext file like below

public virtual DbSet<UDFResult> StringValue { get; set; }

       
Second try:

IQueryable<UDFResult> state = _context.Query<UDFResult>().FromSql($"select dbo.GetDetail('{form.ValueString}','State') AS value");
List<UDFResult> l = state.ToList(); 

Not getting exception but the value in result is blank.

Any help will be appriciated and also I would be interested in seeing an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, 
I have also added image regarding blank result in the question.